# What is the difference between a field and a property in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently trying to understand the difference between fields  (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) and properties (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/properties.html).

They are both somehow defined as a "subfield/subproperty" of a type/mapping property, both can have separate types and analyzers (as far as I understood it), both are accessed by the dot notation (`mappingProperty.subField` or `mappingProperty.property`).

The docs are using the terms "field" and "property" randomly, I have the feeling, for example:

> Type mappings, object fields and nested fields contain sub-fields,
>   called properties.

What is the difference between properties and (sub-)fields? How do I decide if I have a property or a field?

In other words, how do I decide if I use

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": { 
      "properties": {
        "myProperty": { 
          "properties": {

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": { 
      "properties": {
        "myProperty": { 
          "fields": {

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are no differences, both words are merely synonyms.

Comment: @Val But why are there different doc pages then , which implies that there's an actual technical difference?

Comment: Well, you're right, there are slight differences. `properties` is a keyword to denote that you'll define fields/properties of an object (whether at root level or within an object type) and `fields` is a keyword to denote sub-fields of a given field (usually a `keyword` sub-field of a `text` field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Subfields are indexed from the parent property source. While sub-properties need to have a "real" value in the document's source.

If your source contains a real object, you need to create properties. Each property will correspond to a different value from your source.

If you only want to index the same value but with different analyzers then use subfields.

> It is often useful to index the same field in different ways for
>   different purposes. This is the purpose of multi-fields. For instance,
>   a string field could be mapped as a text field for full-text search,
>   and as a keyword field for sorting or aggregations:

(sorry I find its hard to explain =| )

Comment: Another way to say this - is that a field is for creating indexes on your properties. They telling Elastic you want to create an index of different type for the property.  For instance, you may have a property, say 'speed', indexed as type text, but you want it to also have an index type of keyword, or int or both - this is where you would create a field.
These indexes are useful for when you are searching.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is an explanation from my current understanding. It may not be 100% accurate.

A `property` is what we used to call field in a RDBMS (a standard relationship db like MySQL). It stores properties of an object and provides the high-level structure for an index (which we can compare to a table in a relational DB).

A `field`, which is linked (or included) into the `property` concept, is a way to index that property using a specific analyzer.

So lets say you have:

- One analyzer (A) to uppercase
- One analyzer (B) to lowercase
- One analyzer (C) to translate to Spanish (this doesn't even exist, just to give you an idea)

What an `analyzer` does is transform the input (the text on a property) into a series of tokens that will be indexed. When you do a search the same analyzer is used so the text is transformed into those tokens, it gives each one a score and then those tokens are used to grab documents from the index.

```
(A) Dog = DOG
(B) Dog = dog
(C) Dog = perro
```

To search using a specific field configuration you call it using a dot:

- The `text` field uses the standard analyzer.
- The `text.english` field uses the English analyzer.

So the fields basically allow you to perform searches using different token generation models.